# How do I load an input driver

Tags: xserver, input

This is an academic excerise to grow my knowledge. I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 in a VM from alternate install. Installed xinit, openbox, and emulationstation. I have been playing around with .xinitrc, my profile, bash_profile and the openbox autostart config and am currently having fun starting an xserver and running stuff. All pretty cool stuff !

If I run emulationstation ontop of openbox, I have keyboard input. So I guess openbox loads an input driver at some stage, seems a sensible requirement.

If I simply start an xserver and run emulationstation, I have no keyboard input.

Edit :

I have now also tried with a PS4 controller, that doesn't work either while it does work in my host.

When I plug it into my host, `dmesg` shows :

```
[281291.183386] usb 2-1.3: new full-speed USB device number 10 using ehci-pci
[281291.293591] usb 2-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=054c, idProduct=05c4
[281291.293595] usb 2-1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[281291.293598] usb 2-1.3: Product: Wireless Controller
[281291.293600] usb 2-1.3: Manufacturer: Sony Computer Entertainment
[281291.294936] sony 0003:054C:05C4.000F: Using modified Dualshock 4 report descriptor with gyroscope axes
[281291.306476] input: Sony Computer Entertainment Wireless Controller Touchpad as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.3:1.0/0003:054C:05C4.000F/input/input36
[281291.363481] input: Sony Computer Entertainment Wireless Controller as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.3:1.0/0003:054C:05C4.000F/input/input35
[281291.363956] sony 0003:054C:05C4.000F: input,hidraw3: USB HID v81.11 Gamepad [Sony Computer Entertainment Wireless Controller] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.3/input0
```

When I attach it to my VM, `dmesg` shows :

```
[281291.183386] usb 2-1.3: new full-speed USB device number 10 using ehci-pci
[281291.293591] usb 2-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=054c, idProduct=05c4
[281291.293595] usb 2-1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[281291.293598] usb 2-1.3: Product: Wireless Controller
[281291.293600] usb 2-1.3: Manufacturer: Sony Computer Entertainment
[281291.294936] sony 0003:054C:05C4.000F: Using modified Dualshock 4 report descriptor with gyroscope axes
[281291.306476] input: Sony Computer Entertainment Wireless Controller Touchpad as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.3:1.0/0003:054C:05C4.000F/input/input36
[281291.363481] input: Sony Computer Entertainment Wireless Controller as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.3:1.0/0003:054C:05C4.000F/input/input35
[281291.363956] sony 0003:054C:05C4.000F: input,hidraw3: USB HID v81.11 Gamepad [Sony Computer Entertainment Wireless Controller] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.3/input0
```

So my base install, in the VM, isn't creating an input event for the controller.

Any ideas where I go from here ?

Comment: Install `xserver-xorg-input-all`

Comment: It's already installed. Playing around a bit more, if I start an xserver and run xterm, I can type into it. If I start an xserver and run emulationstation, I have no input. Wonder if it's not a driver issue, but an issue with directing the input to emulationstation ?